# Spring transaction appears read-only without readOnly=true flag

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, transactions

The application is developed with Spring Boot, Spring Data, Hibernate, Hikari connection pool, PostgreSQL. 
With default Postgre installation in our development environment it works fine. But we have issue with installation in customer's environment. 
The error is:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot execute nextval() in
>   a read-only transaction

Unfortunately we have no access to Postgre configuration in customer's network to check transaction defaults. But simple update queries from pgsql and PgAdmin works well with the same credentials.
I have removed all "readOnly=true" from @Transactional annotations - no luck, the same error. Added

```
dataSource.setConnectionInitSql("SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ WRITE");
```

to Hikari datasource configuration. No luck as well. 
Another differences between these two PostgreSQL installation are:

- customer uses 9.5 (we use 9.4)
- customer disabled access to public schema, we have to configure
  another schema in hibernate properties.

The error appears occasionally, the same method works well several times but then throws this exception. Which makes me thinking that some pooled connections are in read-only state, others are not. But why Spring does not explicitly mark every new transaction as read-write , or JDBC level fails to do that? Please help to debug.

Comment: Added a workaround : created a dummy sequence in database and added selection from it as dataSource.setConnectionInitSql(...) . By unknown reason, some connections are opened in read-only mode, but others are read/write . WIth this init.sql , Hikari pool silently ignores read-only connections and uses only read-write ones, usable for our app. It is still unclear why Postgre server behaves this way and how our pool will work in production.